# View SQL Server list of declared variables in SQL batch

Tags: sql-server, variables

Does anyone know if there is a way to view the list of variables that have been declared in a SQL batch? It would be something like this:

```
declare @Variable1 datetime2

select * from [List Of Declared Variables Table]
```

I realize it would be something I would only have access to in the current SQL batch. I was just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: Can we ask why please? I'm interested in how it's done... but I've never needed to do it in many years

Comment: This isn't possible. There are no reflection capabilities built into TSQL. If you explain why you need this maybe we can suggest an alternative approach.